# Using Header function after writing a file

Tags: php

I would like to redirect a user to a specific location after writing into a file.
I know that Header function cannot be used after sending data to the client.
But my question is if fwrite is considered as sending data to the client.

What I want to do is the following.

```
<?php
session_start();
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
//print_r( $data);

$DirAnnonceur = $_SESSION['id'] ."-". $_SESSION['ec'];

$ini_array = parse_ini_file("../cc_custom.ini");
$img_path = $ini_array['img_annonceurs_path'];
$fullPath = $img_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $DirAnnonceur  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$jsonPath = $fullPath . 'imgPosition.json';
//echo $img_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $DirAnnonceur  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;

$arr = array();
foreach($data as $cle => $element)
{
    $arr[$element] = $fullPath . $element;
}

$fp = fopen($jsonPath, 'w');
if(fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))){
    header('Location: ../admin/contact.php');
    //echo json_encode(array("state" => "IMAGE-SAVED-POSITION-OK" , 128));
}
else
    echo json_encode(array("state" => "IMAGE-SAVED-POSITION-KO" , 128));
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Note this php script is called after a click on a save button in my html page.

thanks for helping.

Comment: this has nothing to do with fwrite. header() only works if no **OUTPUT** has gone to the client. any function which produces output directly, or indirectly (e.g. causes warnings/errors) would trigger "headers already sent" errors. you're writing to a file, so no output would be created by that act, but if the file is inaccessible or fwrite otherwise fails. PHP may spit out warnings/errors about that, and those errors/warnings ARE output.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanations, but this doesn't help me to understand why my header redirection is not working (I got no error, because the file is created with the right content).

Comment: check the return value from header(). it'll be boolean false on failure (e.g. headers already sent).

Comment: I made this check  `if (!headers_sent()) header('Location: ../admin/contact.php');` and I can see in the chrome dev console that I get the page itself. What I don't understand is why this doesn't redirect me...

Comment: add `exit` after `header`

Comment: that's what I did, and this change nothing...

Comment: @skunk a - in this case, you have already sent content to client. Please use `headers_sent` with references to determine where.

Comment: @eithedog how do you use `headers_sent` with references?

Comment: headers_sent($filename, $linenum)

Comment: thanks, but still not working as expected. I am using this test to check if hearders_sent before and where but I enter in the if not in the else `if (!headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;} else {
    echo "Headers already sent in $filename on line $linenum\n";
    exit;
}`  What is very strange is if I look to the chrome console, I see the page example.com and I did one more test, if I load in chrome the php page I am redirected to the page....